# HTML Tabs the best way if I only have to support IE10 and above (and other modern browsers)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-10

We're making an internal tool only for Windows 8 users, which is why IE10 is a hard requirement.

I wanted to create Tabs -- and was wondering if there is an easier way (javascript-free?) to make them.

Comment: Yes, using HTML anchors and `:target` pseudo class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Not owner of the code (got it from somewhere, don't remember)

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
     <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
     <div class="content">stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
    <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
    <div class="content">more stuff</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are three methods you could use:

- `:focus` method (works even in IE7, though it's a bit weird there) - [example](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-focus.html)
- `:target` method - [example](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-tabbed-pages.html)
- checkbox hack method (works in IE9+ and the advantage over the first
  two is that doesn't break the back button behaviour) - [example](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-radio-tabs.html)